How to use std::filesystem library when compiling ROS2 package with colcon?
I am trying to compile my first ROS2 package using the std::filesystem library with colon build, but I am getting the following compile error:

function "std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::filename" is not a type name

This is part of the CMake of my package:
...
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()
...

As you can see above, I tried to force the compiler to use C++17.
I am wondering where the ...__cxx11... statement comes from?
I also tried to use std::experimental::filesystem::path::filename without success.

Can you please share your header and source file where you use std::filesystem? This sounds like a C++ issue rather than a CMake issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

On wich ROS2 version and OS are you compiling?

It would help to diagnose if you'd share what compiler you're using. There's plenty GCCs out in the wild with incomplete C++ standards support.

You should not use the __cxx11.
Your header or cpp file must look like this.
#include <filesystem>

std::filesystem::path file_path = "foo.txt";

Please provide how are you using the filesystem lib

I don't think OP has __cxx11 in their code at all. Why and how it gets there is pretty much what the question is about. To my understanding, at least.
